# Start Firebird Service under OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, firebird, firebird2.5

Since OSX Yosemite no longer supports StartupItems i am unable to start the Firebird-Service on Bootup.

I am using the latest Firebird Version 2.5.3.

Does anyone have a script to start the service manually or could tell me how to force OSX to start the service on BootUp.

A manual call to the following command starts the fbguard and fbserver but closes it after a few seconds automatically. Whats wrong?

```
sudo -u Firebird /Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Resources/bin/fbguard -daemon -forever
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Paul response and fix for Firebird SuperServer on Yosemite

http://paulbeachsblog.blogspot.fr/2015/02/yosemite-superserver-and-startupitems.html

Comment: "link only" answers are not allowed, you might want to consider including (or quoting) the most essentialy parts of that blog post.

Comment: I think this should work. But for some reason not for me...

Always after i call:

/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Resources/bin/fbguard -daemon -forever

Firebird starts but closes (crashes?) after a few seconds. What could be the reason?

Comment: Where can i find them on OSX?